# Dovecot login with username and no @domain.com extension

Tags: email, email-server, dovecot, imap, roundcube

I have dovecot setup and working, but i can only login as a linux user without the @domain.com extension. e.g
joe.bloggs is a user on the linux system. i can login using this as the imap username and the user password

> username = joe.bloggs - Allows me to login to roundcube tosend and receive emails.

The problem is i want to be able to set this up to work on my phone and it wont let me enter the imap details without @domain.com.

> username = joe.bloggs@domain.com - Does not work with roundcube or with the android mail app.

How can i configure the imap system to allow me to login as joe.bloggs@domain.com? Will i have to create a linux user called joe.bloggs@domain.com?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use auth-passwdfile.conf.ext with users file.

```
passdb {
  driver = passwd-file
  args = scheme=CRYPT username_format=%u /my/file/path/dovecot.users
}
```

Syntax:

```
user@domain.tld:{passwdtype}password:uid:gid::::
```

Comment: i have found the file in /etc/dovecot/conf.d and i can see the passdb line but im unsure what im meant to do with it in regard to the syntax line

Comment: "dovecot.users" file syntax. More info: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/PasswordDatabase